# Does the Blue Spiny Koopa Shell ever appear on a Koopa?

Tags: mario-series

In Mario Kart, the Blue Spiny Shell is the harbinger of death and broken friendships. But, is there actually a Koopa in the Mario universe that wears this shell clad in spikes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only creature I've found with the **Blue Spiny Shell** is [Sky-Blue Spiny](http://www.mariowiki.com/Sky-Blue_Spiny), and is found in *Paper Mario: The Thousand-Year Door*.

[image: Sky-Blue Spiny]

---

There was a similar one in old [Super Mario Bros. 3](http://www.mariowiki.com/Spiny#Mario_Bros.): [image]

> If they aren't defeated in time, *Spinies* will flip themselves over and their shell will turn from red to green (and from green to blue if it happens a second time), making it faster.